# Problems getting ui-select2 demo for angular to run

Tags: node.js, angularjs, bower, ui-select2

I download the [demo](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2), unzip it, access the demo folder, type bower install and no errors pop up
After that I open index.html, but the widgets don't respond.

The fields are all empty and nonresponsive. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery path is broken in index.html. You need to set it to:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```